# SQL last in Recursion(variable)

Tags: sql-server-2008, recursion

My recursion give me complete structure

For example:
(This example is only for KOMPARTNR=49807, but I have more KOMPARTNR where are more than 500 results.)

How real items structure looks:

```
49807(level 1) -> 50208(level 2) -> 520008(level 3)
49807(level 1) -> 52344(level 2)
49807(level 1) -> 20308(level 2) -> 51005(level 3)
```

Output looks:

```
KOMPARTNR ARTIKEL_NR level
49807     50208      1
49807     52344      1
49807     20308      1
50208     520008     2
520008    530000     3
52344     54500      2
20308     51005      2
51005     53250      3
```

I want the last records from the Structure. From the example above, only 530000, 54500 and 53250 will stand out. But it must be variable. Another KOMPARTNR have another result, that's why I wrote too "How real structure looks".

What I only want from this example:

```
KOMPARTNR ARTIKEL_NR level
520008    530000     3
52344     54500      2
51005     53250      3
```

Here is my recursion:

```
WITH n(KOMPARTNR, ARTIKEL_NR, level) AS
(SELECT SMSTLPOS.KOMPARTNR, SMSTLPOS.ARTNR, 1 AS level
FROM SMSTLPOS
WHERE
SMSTLPOS.KOMPARTNR='49807'
UNION ALL
SELECT SMSTLPOS1.KOMPARTNR, SMSTLPOS1.ARTNR, n.level+1
FROM SMSTLPOS as SMSTLPOS1, n
WHERE n.ARTIKEL_NR = SMSTLPOS1.KOMPARTNR
)
SELECT * FROM n
```

How can I get last records from the Structure?

Comment: @user38111974 what are the results , your query , are giving you?

Comment: Yes, thats my query. I use that for something else, but now I need only the last records from recursion(rows?).

Comment: @user38111974 I rephrase my question: When you are using your query, what are the results you have?

Comment: I used it in Xojo(likes VisualStudio). I need to get all ARTIKEL_NRs, which are at the end in imaginary rows. Now I have got all ARTIKEL_NRs in imaginary rows...

Comment: @user38111974 did you understand what I've asked you ... ?

Comment: Sorry, my result is now as "OUTPUT looks"

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there ...

```
WITH n(KOMPARTNR, ARTIKEL_NR, level) AS
(SELECT SMSTLPOS.KOMPARTNR, SMSTLPOS.ARTNR, 1 AS level
FROM SMSTLPOS
WHERE
SMSTLPOS.KOMPARTNR='49807'
UNION ALL
SELECT SMSTLPOS1.KOMPARTNR, SMSTLPOS1.ARTNR, n.level+1
FROM SMSTLPOS as SMSTLPOS1, n
WHERE n.ARTIKEL_NR = SMSTLPOS1.KOMPARTNR
)
SELECT * FROM n WHERE ARTIKEL_NR NOT IN (SELECT TOP (
                                        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM n) - 2    
                                        ) ARTIKEL_NR
                                        FROM n
                                        )
```

And even simpler

```
WITH n(KOMPARTNR, ARTIKEL_NR, level) AS
(SELECT SMSTLPOS.KOMPARTNR, SMSTLPOS.ARTNR, 1 AS level
FROM SMSTLPOS
WHERE
SMSTLPOS.KOMPARTNR='49807'
UNION ALL
SELECT SMSTLPOS1.KOMPARTNR, SMSTLPOS1.ARTNR, n.level+1
FROM SMSTLPOS as SMSTLPOS1, n
WHERE n.ARTIKEL_NR = SMSTLPOS1.KOMPARTNR
)
SELECT * FROM n EXCEPT SELECT TOP (( SELECT COUNT(ARTIKEL_NR) FROM n) -2) * FROM n
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but this is not ok. My example in question is only example, real I have there more than 500 records in query output. My idea is: A value declaration and if is not next in row, then a value = 1 and in select * from n... give WHERE a value = 1...

Comment: @user3811974 ...  You'll need to rephrase your question according to what you have put in your comment ... My answer fits your question on the premise of what you have given so far and what you are asking for, so far ...

Comment: Yes, second and simpler query works fine, but I need it variable. I am sorry I believed that it is from my Struckture obvious. Again I am sorry.

Comment: Please update your question @user3811974. You don't need to be sorry but as we are spending time on your question , make it sure you have all the right elements in your question when you start asking your question. You save yourself time, and it will spare us a heart attack in the long run ;) Please read this for your future questions http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: I agree. For the next time I make better question ;) I wanted to make very easy example, because this issue is very complicated.